# How do we derive force/acceleration vectors from Einstein's field equations?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, acceleration, warp-drives

I'm new here and I don't have any formal experience in physics beyond A-level. I've been exploring an idea for a space sim game someone else is developing in which propulsion of a spacecraft is achieved through affecting the curvature of local space-time. It's based loosely on the Alcubierre drive. I believe the approach I have in mind can resolve a lot of issues that crop up in this area with more conventional ones, but I want to flesh out the mathematics before I propose it.

I'm imagining a hypothetical machine that can directly warp a local region of space-time as if a body with mass were occupying that region of space. Einstein's field equations neatly relate the interaction between bodies of matter and the curvature of space-time, so I'm wondering if I can imagine this machine warps space-time in a particular way and then use those equations to figure out the force/acceleration vectors produced on objects within that region.

Specifically, in this hypothetical scenario, the machine generates a gravitational "hill" within space-time (I'm imagining this is what happens when negative mass is involved) and then rides on that hill while maintaining a constant distance between itself and the centre of the base of that warp in space-time. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSn50.png

1. How would I describe the curvature of space-time? Is it fair to say that the Ricci scalar is a measure of how "warped" space-time is?
2. How would I go about figuring the velocity of the machine as it rides the gravitational hill it produces behind it?

I'm going to assume that the velocity vector is just the reverse of what it would be if we were dealing with regular gravitational wells produced by objects with positive mass.

Also, it can be assumed that the virtual mass created is static, spherical, neutrally charged, has zero angular momentum, and is within a vacuum, so the Schwarzschild solution of the EFEs can be used. I just don't get how you go from the Schwarzschild solution to velocity/acceleration/force vectors of objects in the region.

Additionally, the cosmological constant can be ignored in this.

Essentially what I want is a way of describing the curvature of space using some metric that is transitive and has total ordering, so I can say the engine is at 50% capacity at one moment and 64% capacity the next. Then I want to have the maths that relates that curvature metric to the velocity of a vessel of mass M and distance R from the centre of the virtual mass.

I hope this all makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a relativist, but I'd guess that (1) GR doesn't speak to anything but gravity so you can only ask about gravitational forces directly and (2) you just transform from the local inertial frame where the motion is trivial into whatever non-inertial frame you standing in when you ask about the gravitational forces and a pseudo-force pops out just like the centrifical pseudo-force in rotational motion.